# How can I upload over 4000 email addresses to Moodle?

Tags: moodle

I work for a non-profit organization and regularly read your Moodle tips. We've been struggling with a problem for days and can't find a good solution to it. Maybe you have some good advice for me?
Problem: We want to upload over 4000 email addresses in Moodle. The participants should then after the upload be enrolled to all courses- access for everyone to all courses.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can upload and enrol users via

Site administration > Users > Accounts > Upload users

At a minimum, the csv file needs to have these 4 fields

```
username,firstname,lastname,email
```

You can also enrol the users on courses by including the course shortname - the headings need to be numbered eg:

```
username,firstname,lastname,email,course1,course2,course3
donaldduck,donald,duck,donald@donaldduck.com,comedycourse,cartooncourse,actingcourse
```

Full instructions here

https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Upload_users#Enrolment_fields

Comment: Thank you so much, Russell. I gonna try this for sure. Wish you best.